# Access multiple cameras on Firefox with javascript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I've managed to access 2 cameras simultaneously on Chrome with Javascript and HTML5 but not on Firefox. Anyway to make it works? or Firefox still not support multiple cameras?

I've attached my code below. Please see if anything I have to rework.

** you have to replace your own device ID to make this code work**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var video = document.getElementById('cam1');
var video2 = document.getElementById('cam2');
var audio, audioType;
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var sHeight = video.height/canvas.height;
var sWidth = video.width/canvas.width;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

    navigator.getUserMedia({video: {deviceId: "8b6cf59198c32c9b3544d9252d96c0d26938780787f0fc04cb162ba978aecf4c"}, audio: false}, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback);
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: {deviceId: "024ad3a357f5dd716e658ba749ac0bc53a4de31f00aba58c35da2736141f51c1"}, audio: false}, onSuccessCallback2, onErrorCallback);

    function onSuccessCallback(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) || stream;
        video.play();

    }

    function onSuccessCallback2(stream) {
        video2.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) || stream;
        video2.play();

    }

    // Display an error
    function onErrorCallback(e) {
        var expl = 'An error occurred: [Reason: ' + e.code + ']';
        console.error(expl);
        alert(expl);
        return;
    }
}


}, false);

</script>
```